# Let $X = [0,1]$ and $\sim$ have the following equivalence relation over $X$: is the quotient first countable?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, first-countable, quotient-set

Let $X = [0,1]$ and $\sim$ have the following equivalence relation over $X$:

$$x\sim y\iff x = y\text{ or }x, y \in {]}0, 1{[}$$

Show that $X/{\sim}$   is not first countable.

====================================================================

First countable means that for any distinct $x, y\in X$, there are $U, V \subset X$ open such that $x\in U, y\in V, x\notin V$ and $y\notin U$.

And

$[x] = \{y\in X : y\sim x\}$

$X/{\sim} = \{[x]: x\in X\}$

I know it should be a simple exercise, but I stuck, any help would be most welcome.
Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$X/\sim$ has exactly 3 points and thus it is first countable. Just like any space with finitely many points or more generally countable number of open subsets.

> First countable means that for any distinct $x, y\in X$, there are $U, V \subset X$ open such that $x\in U, y\in V, x\notin V$ and $y\notin U$.

No, this is not the definition of ["first countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-countable_space)". What you've described is being [$T_1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space).

And indeed, $X/\sim$ is not $T_1$. First of all note that $X/\sim=\{[0],[1/2], [1]\}$ has $3$ points. Furthermore proper, nontrivial open subsets are precisely $\{[0],[1/2]\}$, $\{[1/2]\}$ and $\{[1/2],[1]\}$. So can you separate say $[0]$ from $[1/2]$?

More generally a finite space is $T_1$ if and only if it is discrete. And our $X/\sim$ is not discrete: neither $[0]$ nor $[1]$ are open.

Comment: You cannot separate [0] and [1] because of the [1/2]? I understand [0], [1] belonging to X/$\sim$ but I'm a little lost on the [1/2].

Comment: @Andre perhaps it will be clear if we use some abstract symbols instead. Say $X=\{a,b,c\}$ with topology $\{\emptyset,\{a,b\},\{b\},\{b,c\},X\}$. Then any open neighbourhood of $a$ also contains $b$. You can check this simply by looking at all those open neighbourhoods, one by one. Also note that the choice of $1/2$ in my answer is somewhat arbitrary, it can be $1/3$ or any other point from $(0,1)$. Since $x\sim y$ for any $x,y\in (0,1)$.

Comment: @ freakish Thanks